# Can you tell me why my function to select a random string from a linked list isn't working?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am building a program for a project. One of the requirements for the project is a function that selects a random node from my linked list of 3000 words.

I tried to do this by creating a function that generates a random number from 0 to 2999. After this, I created another function that follows a `for` loop starting from the head and moving to the next node (random number) times.

My random number generator is working fine, but my `chooseRand()` function is not.

Please help, the random number generator and the `chooseRand()` function are the last two functions above `main`. Also, my code is a bit messy, sorry.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int nodeNum;
int chances;
char* secret;



/*Node of linked list*/
typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *start = NULL;
node *current;

/*Void function to print list*/
void printList(struct node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

/*Appending nodes to linked list*/
void add(char *line) {

    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = strdup(line);
    temp->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }
}


void readfile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[512];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        add(buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

node *listSearch(node* start, char *nodeSearched){
    node *p;
    for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        if (strcmp(p->data, nodeSearched) == 0)
            printf("%s", p->data);
    return NULL;
}

node *letterSearch(node* start, int i){
    node *p;
    for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        if (strlen(p->data) == i)
        {
            printf("\n %s", p->data);
            free(p);
            p = NULL;
        }
    return NULL;
}

void chooseRand(struct node* start)
{

    node* p;
    int n;
    p = start;
    for(n = 0; n != nodeNum; n++)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("%s", p->data);
}

void randNum(int lower, int upper)
{
    srand(time(0));
    nodeNum = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;

}

int main(){

    randNum(0, 2999);

    chooseRand(start);





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `n != randNum` should be `n != nodeNum`.

Comment: `randNum` is the function, `nodeNum` is the random number it chooses.

Comment: Why does `randNum` need a loop? Picking a random number multiple times doesn't make it any more random.

Comment: Yes, you are right about randNum not needing a loop and randNode being put instead of randNum, however the code still isn't working for some reason.

Comment: You never fill in the linked list.

Comment: You need to call `readfile()` before calling `chooseRand()`.

Answer (score 1):

As others has said, the problem is that you don't have initialized the linked list yet, because of what your are getting a segmentation fault. So, in addition to initializing the list first, you must also introduce checks in the implementation of the `chooseRand` function, to check that if you reach the end of the list, without reaching the desired index, you stop executing the foor loop, otherwise you will be potentially exposed to segmentation faults.

Improve `chooseRand` implementation, to prevent segmentation fault either, when the linked list is empty, or when the randomly generated `nodeNum` is grater than the the index of the list's last item:

```
void chooseRand(struct node* start)
{
    node* p;
    int n;
    p = start;
    if(p == NULL){
        printf("The list is empty!");
        return;
    }

    // Also, we must stop the iteration, if we are going to pass the end of the list, you don't want a segmentation fault because trying to access a NULL pointer:
    for(n = 0; n != nodeNum && p->next != NULL; n++)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    // If p == NULL, the list was not big enough to grab an item in the `nodeNum` index:
    printf("%s", (n != nodeNum) ? "Not found!" : p->data);
}
```

Initialize the linked list, with the content of some file on disk:

```
int main(){

    randNum(0, 2999);
    
    // Fill the linked list with the content of a file in disk, calling your method:
    char fileName[] = "PutYourFileNameHere.txt";
    readfile(fileName);
    chooseRand(start);
    return 0;
}
```

There is another fix that you must do, and it is free the memory being hold by the pointer field `data` of your structure, in the implementation of your method `letterSearch`. Inside the `if` statement, you're de-allocating the memory hold by the `p` pointer, but you aren't de-allocating the memory assigned to the pointer `p->data`, this will cause a memory leak. When you in the function `add`, initialized `p->data` with the result of the call to the function `strdup(line)`, what this function does is allocate enough memory in the heap, copies to it the buffer pointed by the `line` argument, and give to you back a pointer to the new allocated memory, that you're storing in the `p.data` field; a pointer that you should free when you're done with it, otherwise your program will have potential memory leaks. So I will modify your function `letterSearch` as folollows:

```
node *letterSearch(node* start, int i){
    node *p;
    for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        if (strlen(p->data) == i)
        {
            printf("\n %s", p->data);
            // Free p->data before free p:
            free(p->data);
            free(p);
            p = NULL;
        }
    return NULL;
}
```

References:
[strdup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup)